# Advanced string formatting - Python

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

here is a quick example of what I'm trying to do

```
box = {
    'colour': 'Red',
    'dimensions': {
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '333px',
     }
}

print "The box is %(colour)s, wide %(dimensions.width) and high %(dimensions.height)" %box
```

Is this possible with the standard library?

If not, what libraries would you recommend?

Comment: yes, use str.format http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> box = {
        'colour': 'Red',
        'dimensions': {
            'width': '100px',
            'height': '333px',
         }
    }
>>> print "The box is {colour}, wide {dimensions[width]} and high {dimensions[height]}".format(**box)
The box is Red, wide 100px and high 333px
```

Comment: If using the `.` dot notation in your strings is really important to you then there is a way you can do that as well.

Comment: i see that it works, but how does the dict unpacking work here?  why don't the `width` and `height` need quotes around?

Comment: From the docs: `An expression of the form '.name' selects the named attribute using getattr(), while an expression of the form '[index]' does an index lookup using __getitem__().`

Answer (score 3):

[Yes.](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) You've got it right, except that you should use `{}` instead of `%()`.

Comment: example? and version of python?

Comment: {N} string formatting was introduced 2.4, and you were allowed to use {} instead of {0}, {1} (positional formatting) since python 2.7. Its use is encouraged above %(), especially in the 3.x series as the former is deprecated.
`print('Hello {}, this is {}'.format('world', 'python'))`
Also see the webpage: `http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html`

Answer (score 2):

...also, have a look at [string templates](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings), been around since 2.4

Example

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('$who likes $what')
>>> s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes kung pao'
>>> d = dict(who='tim')
>>> Template('Give $who $100').substitute(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string: line 1, col 10
>>> Template('$who likes $what').substitute(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
KeyError: 'what'
>>> Template('$who likes $what').safe_substitute(d)
'tim likes $what'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but unfortunately only for Python3

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101

**Edit:**

Sorry, this feature also ported in python 2:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print 'Platform: {0.platform}\nPython version: {0.version}'.format(sys)
Platform: linux2
Python version: 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2]
```

Comment: Are you sure? I think this is supported in python 2.7 using the % operator, but I don't have a Python system to hand.

Answer (score 0):

In an object oriented manner, you could have Box as an object and then override the `__str__()` and `__unicode__()` methods to print out the variables such as width and colour in a human-readable string.

Example:

```
class Box():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dimensions = (kwargs.get('width'), kwargs.get('height'),)
        self.colour = kwargs.get('colour')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'The box is {}, wide {}, and {} height'.format(
            self.dimensions[0], self.dimensions[1], self.colour)
```

and here is how you initiate the class:

```
a = Box(height='100px', width='100px', colour='Red')
```

and this is how you print it out:

```
print(a)
```

or

```
myvar = str(a)
```

Note: I put width and height in a tuple.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution I came up with, although the `str.format` methods are probably cleaner, add the following function and then use `"...format string..." % flatten(box)`.

```
def flatten(d, key=None):
    r = d.copy()
    if key is not None:
        r = dict((key+"."+k, v) for k, v in r.iteritems())
    for k, v in r.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            r.update(flatten(v, k))
            del r[k]
    return r
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> flatten(box)
{'dimensions.width': '100px', 'colour': 'Red', 'dimensions.height': '333px'}
>>> print "The box is %(colour)s, wide %(dimensions.width)s and high %(dimensions.height)s" % flatten(box)
The box is Red, wide 100px and high 333px
```